# Can you do subpattern within range for regex?

Tags: regex

My intent is to do something like this:

```
[a-zA-Z\d(%8e)]
```

allow those characters, digits, and the sequence of `%8e`, but not `%` by itself.

The language I'm using is ruby 1.8.7

The reason for sequences like %8e, %2b, (etc.) is dealing with url character encodings and handling them to spit out something apache can understand as a redirect or rewrite in .htaccess

**Edit:**
I don't want any positional dependencies either (e.g. if `%8e` is captured at the end of a string, but not in the beginning, then that's not what I'm looking for)

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9]|%8e)*`?

Comment: what's the language? Also, could you give a few string examples of what you're thinking? Would % be between spaces?

Comment: `[]` is not a range, it is a *character* class. It matches 1 single character defined inside the class. So, there is no way to use *sequences* inside the character class. In POSIX, the `[a-z]` is a *bracket expression*, not a character class, but still it won't match *sequences of chars*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`([a-zA-Z0-9]|%8e)*`

should be what you are looking for.

Just to mind you `\d` should not be in the character class `[]` as iirc some regex engine does not support it.

Test result:

https://regex101.com/r/sB7eT4/1

Comment: oops, I misread your question as "sequence of character,digits and %8e".  If it should only match one character, or one digit, or `%8e`, then just remove the `*` at the end

Answer (score 0):

This is what you mean, I think:

```
([a-zA-Z\d]|%8e)
```